# Boost Djikstra class "boost::property_map> has no member "type"

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have been struggling to implement Djikstra's Algorithm using the Boost framework for some time now, and I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

Using the example found at: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html,

I am getting an error on line 36

```
property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight, g);

class "boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::edge_weight_t, void>" has no member "type"
```

I can't find anyone else having the same issue, and I can't seem to work out what the problem is. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the error tells you precisely what is wrong. There is nothing called `type` in `property_map` class. What exactly are you trying to obtain from there?

Comment: Do you have the same Boost version as the one in the example (1.67.0)?

Comment: Yes I am using 1.67.0. I know there is nothing called type in the `property_map` class, but all of the djikstra examples I have seen (regardless of which version) seem to use this `::type` member, which I just can't seem to find. I can't work out if I'm missing something.

Comment: Try property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t> weightmap = get(edge_weight, g);

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7R1U56Tx3jNco1IQ)

Comment: Could there be an issue that I am using Visual Studio 2017 to run and compile this?

Comment: More likely, your graph type isn't the same as in the example. Please make your sample code _self-contained_ (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I also get red squiggly lines in the VS2017 editor using Boost 1.68.0 and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp, but the example does compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you failed to define the edge-weight property on the graph. E.g.:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54d774cdf5433a4e)</kbd>**

```
using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list</*boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::no_property*/>;

boost::property_map<graph_t, boost::edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g);
```

Doesn't compile. You should add one:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c145d7d56749732)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
      boost::no_property,
      boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> >;

int main() {
    graph_t g(5);
    boost::property_map<graph_t, boost::edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g);
}
```

You can probably simplify a little:

```
auto weightmap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);
```

Or consider using bundled properties:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/913c86dff28e5705)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct EdgeProps {
    double weight = 0.0;
};

using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProps>;

int main() {
    graph_t g(5);
    auto weightmap = get(&EdgeProps::weight, g);
}
```